# Update is not saving in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**views.py**

```
def productslist(request):
    products = Products.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products}
    return render(request,'productslist.html',context)

def productsform(request):
    return render(request,'productscreate.html')

def productsupdate(request):
    return render(request,'productsupdate.html')    



def productsAdd(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.data
        product = Products()
        product.title = request.POST["title"]
        product.description = request.POST["description"]
        product.image = request.FILES.get("image")  
        product = Products(title=data['title'], description=data['description'], image=data['image'])     
        product.save()
        serializer = Productserialize(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)


def products_list(request):
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        product = Products.objects.all()
        serializer = Productserialize(product,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)



class ProductsDetailView(DetailView):
     template_name = "productsdetail.html"
     queryset = Products.objects.all()
     context_object_name = 'products'
     model = Products
     serializer_class = Productserialize

@api_view(['PUT'])
def productupdate(request,pk):
    data = request.data
    prod = Products.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = Productserialize(prod,data=data, many=True)  
    if serializer.is_valid():  
        serializer.save()  
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**detail.html**

```
<form>

      
      
     Title:- {{products.title }} <br><br>
     
     Description:- {{ products.description}}<br><br>

 
     {% if products.image %}
      Image :- <img src="{{products.image.url}}" alt="image"><br><br>
      {% endif %}


 

     <button><a href="/update/{{ products.id}}">Edit</a></button>
    </form>
```

**serializer.py**

```
class Productserialize(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    image = serializers.FileField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Products.objects.create(**validated_data)


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.id = validated_data.get('id', instance.id)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**update.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/update/{{prod.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title:<br>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{ prod.title }}"></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:<br>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" value="{{ prod.description }}">Description</textarea></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% if prod.image %}
        <td>Image:<br>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="{{prod.image.url}}"></td>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" id="update">Update</button></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index, name="index"),
     path('productlist', views.login, name="login"),
     path('productslist', views.productslist, name='productslist'),
     path('productscreate',views.productsform,name='productscreate'),
     path('productsadd', views.productsAdd, name="productsadd"),
     path('api/', views.products_list, name="products_list"),
     path('<int:pk>', ProductsDetailView.as_view(), name='productsdetail'),
     path('update', views.productsupdate, name="productsupdate"),
     path('update/<str:pk>', views.productupdate, name="productupdate"),
]
```

Update is not saving data to rest framework I don't know what is the issue
[image]

When i try to update form data is not saving in database and not displaying in api
I have given html,views and urls.py
I need to update form with html form and i want to display data in api
Please help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: No nothing errors..data is not saving to db and not displaying in api

Comment: Have you tried using pdb to debug if the update is being called correctly or not? What is present in the server logs when you make the API call? Have you tried curl/postman to make request other than the browser?

Comment: Not tried postman but update is not working data is not saving

Comment: Try by removing "instance.id = validated_data.get('id', instance.id)" from update method of product serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like you're updating single object. That is why you're taking pk from url. So very first change you need here is .

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def productupdate(request,pk):
    data = request.data
    prod = Products.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = Productserialize(prod,data=data, many=True)  
    if serializer.is_valid():  
        serializer.save()  
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

change that `many=True` to `many=False`.

and you can also comment .

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.id = validated_data.get('id', instance.id)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

from your serializer. Because your views are already handling that updating logic..